# trying to UPDATE foreign key in two tables joined on 4 columns

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
mysql> show create table named \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: named
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `named` (
  `table_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `table_pk` int NOT NULL,
  `name_type` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `naml` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `namf` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `namt` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nams` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `named_only_pk` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`table_name`,`table_pk`,`name_type`),
  KEY `naml` (`naml`(20)),
  KEY `naml_2` (`naml`,`namf`,`namt`,`nams`),
  KEY `named_only_pk` (`named_only_pk`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> show create table named_only \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: named_only
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `named_only` (
  `pk` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `naml` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `namf` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `namt` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nams` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `naml` (`naml`,`namf`,`namt`,`nams`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

The named table as 30M rows and the named_only table has 2M rows.

The named_only table has a unique constraint on (naml,namf,namt,nams).

The named table came from other tables. The named_only table was filled by:

```
replace into named_only (naml,namf,namt,nams) select naml,namf,namt,nams from named;
```

I set the pk values in named_only after the rows are added with:

```
update named cross join (select @pk:=0) as init set named.pk=@pk:=@pk+1;
```

I am trying to set up named_only_pk in named as a foreign key to the pk in named_only.

I know a query that will work. I can do:

```
update named n1, named_only n1 set n1.named_only_pk = n2.pk where
    n1.naml = n2.naml and n1.namf = n2.namf and n1.namt = n2.namt and n1.nams = n2.nams;
```

This is not on a powerhouse machine, but my laptop.

But it seems as though this is going to take a week. I create indexes of (naml,namf,namt,nams) on both tables. Still was taking a while with no indication of how long it would take.

I tried different variations of selects with limits and could not get anything to work.

I tried exporting the named_only table and using that (and awk) to build SQL insert statements but this seems error-prone.

But is this the only way to do this operation in small enough bunches that it does not try to suck up all the memory in the known universe?

Any suggestions?

ADDED 2020/06/16:

Creating an insert trigger did not work. I created:

```
 DELIMITER $$

 CREATE TRIGGER named_only_after_insert 
 AFTER INSERT ON `named_only` for each row
 begin
 update named n1 set n1.only_pk = NEW.pk
 where n1.naml = NEW.naml and
       n1.namf = NEW.namf and
       n1.namt = NEW.namt and
       n1.nams = NEW.nams;
 END$$

 DELIMITER ;
```

I tried to insert 10 rows (making the op quicker?) and got:

```
 mysql> insert into named_only (naml,namf,namt,nams) select naml,namf,namt,nams from named where only_pk is NULL limit 10;
 ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'named' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

Sigh. Ok. What if it is coming from a third table, a copy of named?

```
 mysql> insert into named_only (naml, namf, namt, nams) select naml, namf, namt, nams from named2 where pk < 10;
 ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

10 is too many?

```
 mysql> insert into named_only (naml, namf, namt, nams) select naml, namf, namt, nams from named2 where pk < 2;
 ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

Obviously not. There is no other query running, so nothing else is holding a lock on the table.

And I am now doing this in a AWS large Ubuntu image. So my laptop is not the issue.

Well, I think I will have to go outside SQL for this. Which seems lame, but O well.

ADDED LATER:

Yes, it was solvable, but not using SQL.

So here it is:

```
 % echo "select naml,namf,namt,nams,pk from named_uniq;" | mysql -u root -p -B --skip-column-names ca_sos_20200615 > n1.txt
 % echo "select naml,namf,namt,nams,table_name,table_pk,name_type from named;" | mysql -u root -p -B --skip-column-names ca_sos_20200615 > n2.txt
 % cat n1.txt n2.txt | sort > n3.txt
 % awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}{if (NF == 4) fk=$4; if (NF == 7) print $5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"fk}' n3.txt > n4.txt
```

Theoretically I can just rename n4.txt to named and import it. Nope. Nothing so easy, because that is a big insert.

So:

```
 % split --lines=10000 --suffix-length=7 n4.txt n4_
 /bin/ls -1 n4_* | awk '{print "echo \""$0"\"; cp "$0" named; echo \"load data local infile '\''/home/ubuntu/named'\'' into table named;\" | mysql -u root --password=root --local-infile ca_sos_20200615"}' | /bin/sh 2>/dev/null
```

And all that in under 3 hours.

Now, how can this be done with SQL?

Comment: Use an after insert trigger on named_only and an auto_increment for pk and then update  the row in named with the generated pk and let it run for the night.

Comment: Might be workable. Will try.

Comment: Can we see the EXPLAIN for your query?